# tensorflow, tf.while_loop: The two structures don't have the same nested structure

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I tried to build a nested loop which is used to create a 2-dim zero-matrix to solve LCS problem (dynamic programming). This is later used in computing the Rouge-L score (the input is tensor, not string), but it always goes wrong raising `ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure.`

I checked out some similar questions and I revise some codes, but it still won't work (the code I put up here is the final code):

1. I changed the shape_invariants. I use len(inner) now to dynamically obtain the shape of inner.
2. Still the shape_invariants, I change 1 into 0 now (the first parameter in shape_invariants). I thought the shape of a scalar is 1 but I checked out some source code on github and I found it all uses 0.

```py
# the origin code is below, in which sub and string are both string(type), len_sub and len_string are both int:

lengths = [[0 for i in range(0,len_sub+1)] for j in range(0,len_string+1)]

# but in the new code that I need, the sub and string are both tensor, so I code like this:

len_string = tf.shape(string)[0]
len_sub = tf.shape(sub)[0]

def _add_zeros(i,inner):
        inner.append(0)
        return i+1, inner
def _add_inners(j, lengths):
    i=0
    inner = []
    _, inner = tf.while_loop(
                cond=lambda i,*_: i<=len_sub,
                body=_add_zeros,
                loop_vars=[i,inner],
                shape_invariants=[0,len(inner)])
    lengths.append(inner)
    return j+1, lengths

lengths = []
j = 0  
_, lengths = tf.while_loop(
                cond=lambda j,*_: j<=len_string,
                body=_add_inners,
                loop_vars=[j,lengths],
                shape_invariants=[0,len(lengths)])
```

```
ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure.  
First structure: type=list str=[0, []]  
Second structure: type=list str=[0, 0]  
More specifically: Substructure "type=list str=[]" is a sequence, while substructure "type=int str=0" is not  
Entire first structure:  
[., []]  
Entire second structure:  
[., .]
```

I don't know why it goes wrong. I'd appreciate it if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Basically what the error message is saying is that your return value is a list while it was expecting it to be a number, this makes sense as you have defined your shape_invariants to be `[0, len(lengths)]` which both are integers thus the second structure defined as `[.,.]` however the first structure is a number and a list `[., []]` which again makes sens as you are passing in the lengths.

TLDR: Either change your `shape_invariants=[0,len(lengths)])` to `shape_invariants=[0,lengths])` or change your `loop_vars=[j,lengths]` to `loop_vars=[j,len(lengths)],`